# Ethernaut King - transfer function doesn't work

Tags: openzeppelin

I'm stuck on King.sol (level 9) of ethernaut even though I know how to solve it. I looked at online solutions - One of which is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract BadKing {

  function becomeKing(address king) public payable {
    (bool result, bytes memory data) = king.call.value(msg.value)("");
    if(!result) revert();
  }

  // OMG NO PAYABLE FALLBACK!!
}
```

The above works. But when I use the `transfer` method. It doesn't.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract BadKing {

  function becomeKing(address payable king) public payable {
    king.transfer(msg.value);
  }

  // OMG NO PAYABLE FALLBACK!!
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
```

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for using solidity 0.5.0?

Answer (score 1):

Because transfer and send are limited to 2300 gas units, the receive function in the king contract is consuming more than 2300. This is the reason it reverts.

While using call instead, the gas has no limit, allowing the receive function to execute completely.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function becomeKing(address payable king) public payable {
    payable(king).transfer(msg.value);
}
```