# Ethernaut King: transfer() and send() doesn't work, but call() succeeds in taking Kingship

Tags: openzeppelin, transfer, send

I was trying to solve the [King](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/9) challenge in Ethernaut, but taking Kingship proved to be a bit tricky:

```js
    // Transaction fails
    function takeTheThroneWithTransfer() public payable{
        payable(kingContractAddress).transfer(msg.value);
    }

    // Transaction fails
    function takeTheThroneWithSend() public payable {
        bool success = payable(kingContractAddress).send(msg.value);
        require(success, "Failed to send Ether");
    }

    // Transaction succeeds, attains Kingship
    function takeTheThroneWithCall() public payable{
        (bool success, ) = kingContractAddress.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(success, "Failed to send Ether");
    }
```

I want to understand why this is the case, why transfer() and send() doesn't work but call() does.

Once Kingship was attained, I was able to submit the level successfully.

This question is kinda similar to [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/116985/ethernaut-king-transfer-function-doesnt-work), but there didn't seem to be a complete explanation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because `transfer` and `send`, both of them are limited to 2300 gas units, but the receive function in the `king` contract is consuming more than 2300. This is the reason it reverts.

While using call instead, the gas has no limit, allowing the receive function to execute completely.

Answer (score 0):

Good walkthrough here to help understand why transfer() and send() don't work but call() does - https://dev.to/nvn/ethernaut-hacks-level-9-king-12